# How to set layout to titleWindow in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

```
<fx:Script>

private function showSuccessDialog(msg:String):void
            {
                var label:Label = new Label();
                label.text = msg;               
                label.width = 290;
                label.x = 20;
                label.y = 30;   

                var btnok:Button = new Button();
                btnok.label = "OK";
                btnok.width = 100;
                btnok.x = 100;
                btnok.y = label.y + 30; 

                titleWindow = new TitleWindow();
                titleWindow.title = "Success";
                titleWindow.width = 300;

//when i add this two elements label and button both are displayed on same position
//my label size increases dynamically so i want to add that button below that label
//here for titleWindow i want to set layout how i can do that

                titleWindow.addElement(label);
                titleWindow.addElement(btnok);

                PopUpManager.addPopUp(titleWindow, this, true);
                PopUpManager.centerPopUp(titleWindow);
            }

</fx:Script>
```

Comment: I removed the Blackberry tag because this question has nothing to do w/ BlackBerry or RIM.  I also edited the question to put all your code in "Code format"--there is a curly bracket button that you can use to do that in future questions.  That said, it is unusual to post a question where your actual question is part of comments in the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming since you're using FX that this is a spark TitleWindow:

```
titleWindow.layout = new VerticalLayout();
```

You can then set layout properties like this

```
(tw.layout as VerticalLayout).gap = 4; //sets the gap between items
(tw.layout as VerticalLayout).paddingLeft = 10;  //sets the left padding
```

etc.

Comment: +1 The use of 'fx' doesn't actually mean he is using a Spark component, only that he is using the Flex 4 (or later) SDK.  However, the use of addElement in his code does mean he is using Spark Components.

Comment: He could of imported the MX TitleWindow and not the Spark one.  Also, I would discourage the use of `(tw.layout as VerticalLayout)`.  Why not just store a local var with the vertical layout, do the property changes and add it to the layout property.  I don't recommend using `as` if it isn't needed.

Comment: yea, that's a good point. There is a performance hit with using `as`, even though the type is not actually changing the type. A traditional cast would've been better or using a local var like you suggested. I guess I was feeling a bit lazy, hence my shortening of `titleWindow` to `tw`.... using a two character variable name is also a bad idea!